# Sencha Touch: dataview inside navigation view inside tabpanel, error adding record to store, TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null

Tags: navigation, sencha-touch-2, dataview, sencha-touch-2.1, tabpanel

I have a **Ext.TabPanel**

Within the first tab, I have a **Ext.NavigationView**

And the navigation view consists of a **dataview** which is bound to a store.

Now, when I add data to the store, i get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null
```

The dataview does not get refreshed with the newly added records although the records have been successfully added to the store. If you navigate to any other screen and come back to this screen that contains the dataview, you will be able to see the newly added records.

What could be the problem ?

NOTE:

1. I tried adding the **dataview** directly to the **tabpanel**, I got the same
   error BUT the dataview got refreshed with the new records.
2. When I tried to add the **dataview** directly to the **viewport**, I did not get any errors and the dataview got refreshed as
   expected.

**EDIT :**

I could force the newly added records to show on the dataview by using the **refresh** method.

But this is just a hack. Naturally, adding a record to a store should automatically reflect in the dataview.

**CODE**

**app.js**

```
Ext.Viewport.add([{
    xtype: 'facebook_type_slider' // slider view
},{
    xtype: 'main', //tab panel view

}]);
```

**Main.js (tab panel view)**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.TabPanel',
xtype: 'main',
config: {
items: [{
        iconCls: 'icon1',
        xtype: 'tab1card',
    },{
        iconCls: 'icon2',
        xtype: 'tab2card',

    }, {
        iconCls: 'icon3',
        xtype: 'tab3card',
    },{
        iconCls: 'icon4',
        xtype: 'tab4card',
    }, {
        iconCls: 'icon5',
        xtype: 'tab5card',
    },
],
},
});
```

**Tab1Card (Navigation View)**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.tab1.Card', {
extend: 'Ext.NavigationView',
xtype: 'tab1card',
config: {       
items: [
    {
        title: 'Home',
        xtype: 'home',
    }
]
},
});
```

**Home view (data view)**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.tab1.Home', {
  extend: 'Ext.dataview.DataView',
  xtype: 'home',
  config: {
        xtype: 'dataview',
        store: 'ProductList'
        height: '100%',
        itemTpl: 
        '<div>'+
        '<p>{text}</p>'+
        '</div>',
      },

});
```

Comment: The idea seems correct, post the relevant parts of your code so we can check if you made any errors.

Comment: It sounds like a problem with the model definition.

Comment: As I said, if i directly add the data view to the viewport, it did not show up any errors when adding data to store. So it should NOT be an error with the model right ?

Error shows up in this particular order of nesting of views